# Send DateTime parameter to a linked server stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, linked-server, sql-server-2017

I need to call a stored procedure on my linked server which has `DateTime` parameters.

I'm currently using the following query

```
SET @RunSP = 'EXEC [Database].[dbo].[sp_MySP] @StartDate = convert(datetime, '''+@S+''') , @EndDate = convert(datetime, '''+@E+ ''') ';
```

I have tried different ways to convert my `DateTime` parameters but every time 
I get the following error:

```
Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: what is the data type for `@S` and `@E` ?

Comment: @Squirrel DateTime. 
`Declare @S datetime
Declare @E datetime

Set @S = N'2017/01/01';
Set @E =  N'2017/01/01';`

Answer (score 0):

convert `@S` and `@E` to string format `YYYYMMDD` and enclosed it with single quote

```
SET @RunSP  = 'EXEC [Database].[dbo].[sp_MySP] @StartDate = ''' + convert(varchar(10), @S, 112) + ''', @EndDate = '''  + convert(varchar(10), @E, 112) + ''''
```

Hint : do a `print @RunSP` to view the output

```
Example @RunSP Output :
EXEC [Database].[dbo].[sp_MySP] @StartDate = '20170101', @EndDate = '20170101'
```